# Is there a strongly typed csv reader in python?

Tags: python, csv

I am using the `csv` python package to read a csv file like this:

```
r = csv.DictReader(open(r'd:\aaa.csv', 'rb'))
for row in r:
  print row
```

The problem is that all the values in the resulting dictionary are strings and I need them to be converted to the respective types. I have a mapping between column names and the types.

Are there any shortcuts here or do I have to do it all myself?

**EDIT**

I have marked https://stackoverflow.com/a/9720733/80002 as the answer. Only, I have slightly modified it. There is no point to use `DictReader` if I am going to postprocess it anyway, so here is my modification of the Sven's code:

```
r = csv.reader(open(r'd:\aaa.csv', 'rb'))
header = r.next()
converters = [converters_map[c] for c in header]
for row in r:
  row = {title:converter(value) for title, converter, value in zip(header, converters, row)}
  print row
```

Comment: If you end up writing a library wrapping `csv` to do this, I believe others would benefit from it as well. That said, it shouldn’t be that hard.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but related: Using [`quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC) converts unquoted fields to `float`.

Comment: I don't know of anything ready to be used that way. So I'd go with writing the mapping reader by myself. If you take a look at the source code for the `DictReader` it's very simple (it doesn't even inherit from anything).

Comment: If using NumPy is an option for you, have a look at [`numpy.genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt).  It supports custom converters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a dictionary of converter functions converting strings to the respective types, then all you need is

```
with open("d:/aaa.csv", "rb") as input_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(input_file)
    for row in reader:
        row = {k: converters[k](v) for k, v in row.items()}
        print row
```

(Python 2.7.  For earlier versions use `dict()` instead of the dictionary comprehension.)

You can wrap this code in a generator function (simply use `yield row` instead of `print row`).

Comment: I have edited my question. You seem an experienced python developer, do you think it is more efficient to use the `reader` and `zip` three collections like I do in the modified version of your answer?

Comment: @mark: I think your approach is perfectly fine, and it certainly isn't less efficient than the code in this answer.  I'd expect this task to be I/O-bound for large files, so probably your code isn't more efficient either.  As always, you'll have to measure yourself if you want a definite answer (but if you do, be aware of biases introduced by caching).  I can't see any reason *not* to use your modified approach, though.